# Nativescript Ios Vertical align

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Faced an unpleasant problem

help me please

When trying to align to the bottom of the page, the IOS unit does not completely go down
**iosOverflowSafeArea** did not help

```
<GridLayout columns="*,*" rows="*" row="1" col="0" class="project-type-content"  width="100%" [iosOverflowSafeArea]="true">
    <StackLayout width="100%" row="0" [col]="i" *ngFor="let item of projectTypes; let i=index" class="debug" verticalalignment="bottom" [iosOverflowSafeArea]="true">
        <StackLayout width="75%" (tap)="onProjectTypeChoose(item.urlPrefix)" class="debug" [iosOverflowSafeArea]="true">
            <GridLayout columns="*" rows="auto, auto" height="auto">
                <StackLayout class="btn-type-choose" col="0" row="0">
                    <ns-rounded-button fontColor="#fff" borderColor="#fff" color="#fff" [text]="item.title" [bg]="item.bg"
                                       width="100%"></ns-rounded-button>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout width="100%" col="0" row="1" class="project-type-item">
                    <Label [text]="item.subTitle" width="100%" class="project-type-item-title monserrat regular"></Label>
                    <!--<Image [src]="item.image" stretch="aspectFill" class="project-type-item-image"></Image>-->
                    <HtmlView [html]="item.description" width="100%"></HtmlView>
                    <Image src="~/assets/images/firstScreenShadow.png" width="100%" horizontalAlignment="center"></Image>
                    <Label text="What`s New:" class="whats-new-title monserrat semi-bold"></Label>
                    <Label *ngIf="item.updateText && item.updateText[0]" [text]="item.updateText[0]" class="project-type-item-wats monserrat regular"></Label>
                    <Label *ngIf="item.updateText && item.updateText[1]" [text]="item.updateText[1]" class="project-type-item-wats monserrat regular"></Label>
                    <StackLayout width="100%" class="tap-to-choose" height="20">
                        <Button text="Tap to choose" class="tap-to-choose-btn" width="60%"></Button>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </GridLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

http://prntscr.com/mww4y3

Comment: Can you share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: Hello
I noticed that any child has these indents